# convert ASCII to hex (.scc compatible )

Tags: hex, ascii, closed-captions

I'm looking into generating [.scc captions](http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/DOCS/SCC_FORMAT.HTML) that is where text is represented in hex. In the above shared link, it gives an example where a string: `"(horn honking)"` is represented as

```
a820 68ef f26e 2068 ef6e 6be9 6e67 2029
```

However when I try to use any of the available hex to ASCII converters I don't get the exact string:   `¨ hïòn hïnkéng )`

Does anyone know what conversion is used here?

Answer (score 0):

[ttconv](https://github.com/sandflow/ttconv) can convert SCC files to text-based formats, like TTML, IMSC, SRT, VTT...

```
pip install ttconv
tt.py convert -i <input .scc file> -o <output .ttml file>
```